# Make Regex for special characters

Tags: regex, swift, boolean, uitextfield, swift3

I am trying to make it so that I have a UITexField that returns false when checked by a method if it has anything but letters in it, I have tried to create a RegEx, but have not been able to get it to work.

```
func checkNames(name: UITextField, text: UILabel) -> Bool {

    let regEx  = "[,./-=+}{[]`~'!@£$%^&*():;?0-9]"
    let regExTest = Predicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", regEx)
    let charResult = regExTest.evaluate(with: name.text)


    if name.text != nil && charResult == false {
        text.textColor = UIColor(red: 124, green: 252, blue: 0)
        return true

    } else {
        text.textColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0)
        name.text = nil
        name.placeholder = "Alphabetical Name Required"
        return false
    }
}
```

I want it to return false if it has anything but letters.

Comment: If you want to match a string that consists of only letters, you should consider `"^[\\p{L}\\p{M}]*$"` pattern.

Comment: How would I use this? If it had anything but letters would it return true or false?

Comment: Well, `MATCHES` requires a full string match. If `"^[\\p{L}\\p{M}]*$"` matches the input, you get *true*. Note that `\p{L}` matches any Unicode base letter, and `\p{M}` matches any diacritic.

Comment: I guess you can use something like `if name.text.rangeOfString("^[\\p{L}\\p{M}]+$", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) != nil {
    return true
}`. The `+` requires at least 1 character to be present in the input.

Comment: If you want to check only for Alphabetical letters, you can use `NSCharacterSet` to check that the string contains only char in the set, and you can also use `invertedSet()` if needed.